# C++ and Qt: observer pattern error

Tags: c++, qt, observer-pattern

I am trying to implement a simple observer pattern to update widgets with relevant info for a Car Model. I keep getting a rather perplexing error for the update method of my Observer pattern, where the compiler seems to fail to recognize the type of the parameter being passed. This is the header for Observer:

```
#include "Subject.h"

class Observer
{
public:

    virtual void update(Subject &car) = 0;
};
```

Subject header file:

```
#include <QList>

#include "Observer.h"

class Subject
{
protected:

    QList<Observer *> m_observers;

public:

    virtual void registerObserver(Observer &) = 0;
    virtual void removeObserver(Observer &) = 0;
    virtual void notifyObservers() = 0;
};
```

And the the implementation for the Subject (class Car inherits Subject interface):

```
//
// Subject interface implementation
//
void Car::registerObserver(Observer &observer)
{
    m_observers.append(&observer);
}

void Car::removeObserver(Observer &observer)
{
    int i = m_observers.indexOf(&observer);

    if (i >= 0)
        m_observers.removeAt(i);
}

void Car::notifyObservers()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < m_observers.size(); ++i)
        m_observers.at(i)->update(*this);
}
```

However, the compiler gives me an error at the notifyObservers method:

```
/home/dylan/Desktop/CarModel/Car.cpp:50: error: no matching function for call to ‘Observer::update(Subject&)’

 candidate is: /home/dylan/Desktop/CarModel/Observer.h:11: virtual void Observer::update(int&)
```

Uhhhh.... what?? As you can see, the compiler seems to think that the parameter for update is a reference to an int. Is this because my Observer header is abstract? I haven't written an implementation for it yet, so perhaps this is why?

Comment: Is `Subject` declared at the point you define `Observer`?

Comment: Yes. I forgot to add the include for the Observer header above, though it was in my code already.

Comment: Where is it not? It is in the Observer header. I just forgot to add it  there initially here, but it was in my code.

Comment: Kind of an aside, but you do know about Qt's signals and slots, right? That makes it pretty trivial to implement the observer pattern without reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Yeah, now that I think about it it would probably just be easier to implement it with Signals and slots as you described.

Comment: Why do you pass reference, and then pass the reference parameter as the pointer. Did you guarantee that passes parameter won't be destroyed right after registerObserver call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a circular dependency between `Observer` and `Subject`. You can avoid it by forward-declaring `Subject` in `Observer.h` instead of including `Subject.h`:

```
class Subject; // forward declaration

class Observer {
  ...
};
```

And do the same in the `Subject.h`:

```
class Observer; // forward declaration
class Subject {
  ...
};
```

Comment: I see it now. That was a rather dumb mistake on my part.

Answer (score 2):

You have a cyclic include dependency. `Observer` includes `Subject` and `Subject` includes `Observer`. Now the header guards will take care of preventing infinite inclusion, but still one of the headers has to be included first, they cannot be included both at the same time. It happens that the first one to be included is `Observer`, and at that point `Subject` is not yet declared.

Luckily, you don't seem to need any of those includes. You can replace them with a forward declaration:

```
class Subject;

class Observer
{
public:

    virtual void update(Subject &car) = 0;
};
```